# How to generate IL source code with csc (C# compiler) or dmcs (mono C# compiler)?

Tags: c#, mono, il, csc

gcc has an option of -s to generate assembly source code. Does csc (MS C# compiler) or dmcs (mono C# compiler) have equivalence? I mean do those compilers provide an option to generate IL source code that can be read not the execution binary?

Comment: I am pretty sure csc JUST compiles to IL, the framework it runs on turns it into executable code at runtime.

Comment: Actually, Mono contains both csc, gmcs and dmcs - that's just a steps of Mono C# compiler evolution, when it supports generics and dynamics. In Mono 2.8+ they are the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very easy to get to the IL: just use [`ildasm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). The `/text` option prints the result to the console, which you can divert to a file.

Comment: You could also use Cecil to extract it, but that's not as straight-forward.

Answer (score 2):

A C# compiler always generates IL ([CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) in the case for .net), because thats the way .net works, but if you mean you want to precompile this in to machine code to speed up execution you can use ngen.exe (see [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)).

**If you just want to see the generated IL you can use [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).**