# Visual Studio to save CIL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cil

Can I get visual studio to save the intermediate code when I compile a c# program? I'm trying to learn how to program a CIL program and think this would be useful as I can't find any documentation.

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can use a decompiler like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) for this.

Comment: In practice this isn't useful, but occasionally I find myself inspecting the IL using ILSpy.  VS will not produce intermediate artifacts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate IL source code with csc (C# compiler) or dmcs (mono C# compiler)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231983/how-to-generate-il-source-code-with-csc-c-compiler-or-dmcs-mono-c-sharp-comp)

Comment: Your compiled program _is_ CIL.  You can view it in a human-readable form by loading it into `ildasm` or one of many freely available decompilers.  The compiler only writes IL in its binary form; it will not let you output to a symbolic IL format.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's a good idea to code directly into CIL. see the [compilation process of a C# program](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/compilation-process-of-a-c-sharp-program1)

Maybe, can help you visual studio tools, specifically `developer command prompt`, run command `ildasm` and open your assembly (`*.dll` or `*.exe` file) and the code CIL is revealed

This is a common problem for businesses, see more in [Why You Need Obfuscation?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms227271%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)